# Stretch jumbotron to fit all of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to make the jumbotron fit all of the page, because now its not stretched full in the bottom. I tried position fixed, but that made a problem when I get more content in the container its must be able to scroll.

bootply: http://www.bootply.com/125955

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell your jumbotron technically fits all of the page, You're styling the inner container with background colour and borders which makes it appear like it doesnt fit the page.

Take the background-color and border styles off .container, and add them to .jumbatron also add width:100% to .jumbatron if you want it the entire screen width.

Comment: The problem is the bottom of the jumbotron. If you open it with full screen in the bootply you will notice the white bottom.

Comment: Do you mean the gap inside or outside the box?

Comment: That gap is being caused because the jumbatron isnt set to the ful height of the page. See this http://www.bootply.com/125970 I made the html, body and jumbatron 100% height, if you dont want jumbatron to be 100% height, take the background colour off jumbatron and apply it to the body tag